# Query not returning result if the join fails (how to get it to return zero)

Tags: mysql, join

My query is trying to find monthly records with missing days, ie if month has 31 days but less than 31 records I want to detect it. This works fine unless all 31 records are missing when nothing is returned! (By the way Daily is a big table). So how do I get the transmitters with no records at all in a particular month to return zero?

```
  SELECT SUM(w.amount) AS MonthlyTotal,COUNT(*) AS Days,DAY(LAST_DAY('2016-06-01')) AS DaysInMonth 
    FROM Daily  w,Transmitter t 
    WHERE t.SiteID='1907' AND t.UtilityID='1' AND w.TransmitterID=t.TransmitterID  AND NOT t.deleted
    AND w.TimeStamp  BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND LAST_DAY('2016-06-01') GROUP BY t.TransmitterID;
```

Comment: So if you have 1000 transmitters and only 5 of them have data for a month, you still want all 1000 rows (with 995 reporting 0)?

Comment: yes exactly I want all transmitters to always return a result. If no records at all in a month return zero

Comment: You need something to act as a placeholder for the months with no values. A "calendar" table will be of assistance here. There are many internet posts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going into the main problem, there are a few more issues with the query:

- the use of string literals (`'1907'` `'1'`)  for values that are compared with columns that seem to have integer type (`SiteID`, `UtilityID`). If the columns are integers, use integers, not strings:

  ```
  WHERE ... t.SiteID = 1907 AND t.UtilityID = 1
  ```
- using `BETWEEN` and `LAST_DAY()` for datetime/timestamp comparisons. This - assuming that the `w.Timestamp` column is indeed a `TIMESTAMP` will give you incorrect results, unless all your timestamps have `00:00:00` time part. The `LAST_DAY('2016-01-01')` will be `'2016-01-31 00:00:00'` and you lose the whole last day of the month, except the very first second.
  If you change that to `BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2016-07-01` is somewhat better but still wrong as you you'll get a few results from the next day (in July)!
  One way that works correctly and with all datatypes (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`) is to use inclusive-exclusive range checks, with `>=` and `<`:

  ```
  WHERE ... w.TimeStamp >= '2016-06-01' AND w.TimeStamp < '2016-07-01'
  ```

  If the `t.Timestamp` column is of `DATE` type, then ok, `BETWEEN` can be used although I prefer the consistency of the above suggested code.
- using old ANSI syntax without `JOIN`. This is not an error but it's harder for debugging when there are many tables and error-prone (we might forget a joining clause):

  ```
  FROM Daily w, Transmitter t 
  WHERE ... AND w.TransmitterID = t.TransmitterID AND ...
  ```

  It's better (in my opinion) to use the new (since 1992 ;) explicit `JOIN` syntax. It's also easier to change an `INNER` join to a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` outer join:

  ```
  FROM Daily w JOIN Transmitter t
       ON w.TransmitterID = t.TransmitterID  
  WHERE ... AND w.TransmitterID = t.TransmitterID AND ...
  ```

Now for the main problem, the solution is to start from the `Trasmitter` table and then `LEFT JOIN` the details (`Daily`) table:

```
SELECT 
    t.TransmitterID,
    SUM(w.amount)                        AS MonthlyTotal,
    COUNT(w.TransmitterID)               AS Days,
    DATEDIFF('2016-07-01', '2016-06-01') AS DaysInMonth 
FROM Transmitter t LEFT JOIN Daily w 
               ON  w.TransmitterID = t.TransmitterID  
               AND w.TimeStamp >= '2016-06-01' 
               AND w.TimeStamp  < '2016-07-01'
WHERE t.SiteID = 1907 
  AND t.UtilityID = 1 
  AND NOT t.deleted
GROUP BY t.TransmitterID ;
```

Comment: I always quote the values that going to be inserted by my code (php) so that the query doesn't break if the value isn't set didn't realise that might be inefficient.

Comment: I suggest you read this, if you haven't already: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) PHP is not my area so I'm not sure what API/libraries is best but I would think that if the column is integer and the value is an integer (in PHP), then the library should not add quotes.